# Regex that optionally catches all within quotes

Tags: regex

I have comma-separated tuples as an input. Each tuple contain three elements separated by comma: number, text and number. Each element may be absent (empty string).

Text may be wrapped in quotation marks but optionally, it gets wrapped in case when there's a comma or whitespace within a text. An example of the input:

```
(1,Item1,1),(,"Item 2",2),(3,"With,comma",3)
```

Is it possible to write a regex that fetches elements from a tuples?

One of my attempts is next `\((.*?),"?(.*?)"?,(.*?)\)` but it fails on the tuple where text has comma inside.

Here's where I test it: [regex101.com/r/2RetnU/1](https://regex101.com/r/2RetnU/1)

Comment: It's not completely impossible, but generally a bad idea. More test cases for you: `(1, "Item(with\"escaped\"quotes and(parentheses)")`

Comment: @tripleee Well, the regex in my example handles your case, it just fails when there's a comma insite a string. look here https://regex101.com/r/2RetnU/1

Comment: Try `"[^"]*"`instead for the quoted string. A better synthesis is something like `\(([^),]*|"[^"]*")(,[^),]*|"[^"]*")*\)`

Comment: @tripleee it handles it well except for the example that you provided where it skips the last number element in a tuple. Check it by a link that I posted earlier.

Comment: It's not hard to extend to require specifically a 3-tuple but again, you really want a parser instead of a regex.

Comment: If there are always digits before final `)` [try replace last `.*?` with `\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/37HuVd/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\((\d*),(([^()",]|\\[(),"])*|"([^"]|\\")*"),(\d*)\)
```

`Tuple1 = \1`, `Tuple2 = \2`, `Tuple3 = \5`

Tested on:

```
(1,"Item(with\"escaped\"quotes and(parentheses)",3),(2,escaped\, non-

\"quoted\" text \, separated and with \(parentheses\)
,88),(1,Item1,1),(,"Item 2",2),(3,"With,comma",3),
(23,Item1\, Item2\,\"Item 3\",99),(2,,88),(,,)
```

- This RegEx respects the possibility that the string tuple might be escaped or enclosed in double quotes.
  As (for further processing) you need to know if you have an escaped string, the non-escaped string includes the double quotes.
- It requires that the minimum tuple (all empty) includes the separators `,`

1. To be a set of tuples the string requires these character to appear in this order: `(,,)`, in between there might be more characters.
2. Catching the digits in tuple 1 and 3 is trivial: `\d*`
3. The tuple 2 as string splits in 2 variants:

   1. Escaped string: `([^()",]|\\[(),"])*`
      The appearance of the meta characters `,()"` in the string is not allowed, except when having a leading `\` escape character.
   2. Quoted string: `"([^"]|\\")*"`
      Here only the `"` double quote is a meta character that must only appear escaped.
   3. Escaping of meta character `\` is not required, as the tuple-definition is strict enough, except there is a very special, for the tuple-sets syntactically false construction over multiple tuples.
      Accepting this the RegEx is robust against some escaping faults like `(1,"\",3)` or `(1,unquoted\,3)`, but sensitive against faults in the tuple-set skeleton.

As there is no edge detection `^ ... $` the regex will walk over multiple lines if the `\n` is not used as a delimiter.

Comment: Did this work for you? Is there something you need to improve?